# I cant get the most basic sed command to execute on command line

Tags: command-line, sed

I feel like a total newb. Why does this not work?

```
$ echo foobar > textfile
$ sed /foo/bar/ textfile
sed: can't find label for jump to `ar/'
```

I've also tried `sed "/foo/bar/" textfile` and `sed '/foo/bar/' textfile`, which all yields the same error.

Using ubuntu 8.04 and GNU sed version 4.1.5 through bash.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this: `sed 's/foo/bar/' textfile`.

- Quotes around the statement are good practice
- `s` for substitute. It is the command you want to execute. `foo` is the search term `bar` the replacement.

There is a lot of information on sed online. Eg.: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one/

Answer (score 2):

You need to give `sed` a command; it parsed what you gave it as a search pattern `/foo/` followed by the command `b ar/` (branch to label `ar/`).  You probably meant 's/foo/bar/' meaning replace the first instance of `foo` with `bar` in every line.